# How can I get Text from AutocompletedTextview in Android?

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

I want get the text from the Android AutoCompletedTextview data in the program for that I write the following code :

```
autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchField);
String starttext= autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
```

but the value selected in the Autocompletedtextview not getting how can i do.

Comment: Please see my answer and if you have any issue then tell me or if my answer is helping you then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code into your onCreate() method, it will solve your problem.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.i("SELECTED TEXT WAS------->", arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
        String starttext=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    }
});
```

Comment: String starttext= autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().trim();
             String endtext= autoCompleteTextView1.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: @user1787493 what is the value of starttext?

Comment: that is variable i am holding the value of Autocompletedtextview ?

Comment: @user1787493 I mean what is the log value if you are select anyone value from autocompletetextview?

Comment: ya i want get the seleted text ?

Comment: @user1787493 What is the Logcat value of this line. Log.i("SELECTED TEXT WAS------->", arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Auto complete textview

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Comment: You should extract the helpful information from that training. Not simple put OP find again in very big tutorial. He didn't ask for tutorial